# Galaxy S7 types text in reverse order

Tags: android, jquery, maskedinput

I have a jquery masked input plugin. One of its instances set to credit card input field. But there is some bug on Galaxy S7 mobile: digit appears after cursor and cursor stays on its initial place. Any ideas how to fix?

```
<input type="text" id="pan" name="pan">
$('input[id="pan"]').mask("9999 9999 9999 9999");
```

Comment: Which Android version are you using? Is this an Android application (like Ionic/Cordova app) or a web? In case of web, what navigator are you using?

Please, post this info in your question

Comment: Usual web site. Android 6.0, device - S7 Galaxy

Comment: Are you using default Android web navigator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your website includes both `LTR` and `RTL` you might wanna force that input to `LTR` with both direction and bidi-override:

```
<input type="text" id="pan" name="pan" style="direction: ltr; unicode-bidi: bidi-override;">
```

Answer (score 1):

Check reverse key

```
  $('input[id="pan"]').mask("0000 0000 0000 0000", {reverse: true/false});
```